# Is it possible to convert a SQL Server CTE query to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I'm migrating the following SQL Server query

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT 
       ID, StartAptDate, EndAptDate, 
       RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY StartAptDate ASC)
   FROM 
       Appointments 
   WHERE 
       StylistId = 1 
       AND StartAptDate > CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GetDate(), 112) AS DATETIME)
)
SELECT 
    FirstApptAvail = min(a.EndAptDate)
FROM 
    CTE a
INNER JOIN 
    CTE b ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
WHERE 
    datediff(minute, a.EndAptDate, b.StartAptDate) >= 15 
    AND (CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), a.StartAptDate, 108) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '1900-01-01 07:57:57' AND '1900-01-01 18:59:59' 
    AND CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(8), a.EndAptDate, 108) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '1900-01-01 07:57:57' AND '1900-01-01 18:59:59') 
    AND ((DATEPART(dw, a.StartAptDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

After I migrated the database to postgres I modified the start/end column names above to simply "start" and "end". It turns out postgres doesn't like the "end" name so I've been attempting to escape it, but as I'm also using the DATE_PART function, I need to respect single quotes. Here is what I have so far, but I'd love some help rounding out the final conversion (assuming this can be ported to postgres)

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (SELECT id, start, "end", RowNumber =               
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by start asc) 
  FROM api_appointment
  WHERE employee_id = 1 AND start > now())
  SELECT FirstApptAvail = min( a."end" )
  FROM CTE a
  INNER JOIN CTE b ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
  WHERE DATE_PART('minute', a.start - b.start) >= 0
  AND a.start >= '1900-01-01 07:57:57'
  AND a.start <= '1900-01-01 18:59:59'
  AND a."end" >= '1900-01-01 07:57:57'
  AND a."end" <= '1900-01-01 18:59:59');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fairly reasonable. It's hard to be sure without the schema and some sample data (http://sqlfiddle.com/ is good for this).

`end` must be quoted because it's a keyword for `CASE WHEN .. THEN .. END`.

A few tidy-ups: Use `row_number() OVER (...) AS row_number` not `RowNumber = row_number() OVER (...)`. Indent the CTE term. Quote "start" too, who knows when it might become a keyword in SQL; it's already syntax-highlighted by Stack Overflow's SQL highlighting after all. I prefer to use the standard `current_timestamp` instead of the non-standard `now()`, though the effect's the same.

You don't need `WITH RECURSIVE` (and it shouldn't work) because the CTE doesn't have a recursive term; there's no `UNION ALL ... SELECT ... FROM cte`.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
      id, "start", "end", row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "start" ASC) AS row_number
  FROM api_appointment
  WHERE employee_id = 1 AND "start" > current_timestamp
)
SELECT min( a."end" ) AS FirstApptAvail
FROM cte a
INNER JOIN cte b ON a.row_number = b.row_number - 1
WHERE DATE_PART('minute', a.start - b.start) >= 0
  AND a."start" >= '1900-01-01 07:57:57'
  AND a."start" <= '1900-01-01 18:59:59'
  AND a."end" >= '1900-01-01 07:57:57'
  AND a."end" <= '1900-01-01 18:59:59';
```

That said, I suspect there'll be a simpler way to do what you want, but I'd want to see some sample data to see. I also think you will want to investigate PostgreSQL's [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) and [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION), which are great for this kind of job. Range types are GiST indexable for operations like overlap tests.

Oh, that's it. Use `lead` if you can't use range types. Something like:

```
SELECT min("end")
FROM (
   SELECT 
     id, "start", "end", 
     lead(id) OVER w AS next_id, 
     lead("start") OVER w AS next_start, 
     lead("end") OVER w AS next_end
   FROM appointment
   WHERE employee_id = 1 AND "start" > current_timestamp
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY "start")
) AS appts
WHERE appts."end" <> appts.next_start;
```

(See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77f63/6)

You'll need to handle the case where the next available appointment is *now*, before the next booked appointment. I'd probably just generate a virtual appointment with a UNION ALL that ends at `current_timestamp`, rounded to the hour if necessary.

Here's a formulation using tzranges. I was surprised not to find a simple and obvious way to do this with an indexable self join, but I don't know the range types well. This handles the case where the next available app't is now (rounded to nearest hour), or when it's after all current appointments are finished:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/712cb/4

If you're only interested in the next time, you can just tack on `ORDER BY 1 ASC LIMIT 1`.

If you want the soonest 1-hour block, just use `upper(booked_time) + INTERVAL '1' HOUR` to generate the upper bound, instead of the using the lower bound of the next time slot.

Comment: Also, here's the same data expressed as range types. They don't seem as useful as I thought for this, or I'm not smart enough to work out how to use them for it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/712cb

Comment: wow -totally blown away by the completeness of your answer! thanks for taking the time to help! one question -your 2nd snippet using "lead" -is this the proposed solution (essentially improving upon the original) ?

Comment: @ToranBillups The `lead` window function is probably your best option, yes. You can probably avoid selecting the inner `id`, just leave that out. Try and see.